# Chart content overlaps axes with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm using d3.js to create a graphical grid with 2 axis. Data is displayed using cells whose color will change based on the data value. An simple example is visible [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0xPTvK?p=preview). The chart is created as an svg image. I have a problem with the clipping of the data area : when zooming and panning, the data overlaps the axes. You can see this in the provided example, by clicking on the chart content and dragging up or left.

Does someone know how I can make the data to disappear under the axes?

Here is the typescript code I used to create the chart:

```
let cellSize = 49;
let borderSize = 5;
let margin = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40 };

function createChart() {
    // Create test data
    let count = 500;
    let perLine = 50;
    let markers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let id = i + 1;
        let line = Math.floor(i / perLine) + 1;
        let point = i % perLine + 1;
        markers.push({id: id, line: line, point: point});
    }
    //---

    let lineMin = d3.min(markers, (item) => item.line);
    let lineMax = d3.max(markers, (item) => item.line);
    let pointMin = d3.min(markers, (item) => item.point);
    let pointMax = d3.max(markers, (item) => item.point);

    let chart = document.querySelector('.chart');

    let viewWidth = chart.clientWidth - 2;
    let viewHeight = 400;
    let chartWidth = cellSize * (pointMax - pointMin + 1);
    let chartHeight = cellSize * (lineMax - lineMin + 1);

    let point = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([pointMin, pointMax])
          .range([cellSize / 2, chartWidth - cellSize / 2]);

    let line = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([lineMin, lineMax])
      .range([cellSize / 2, chartHeight - cellSize / 2]);

    let pointAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(point)
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickValues(d3.range(pointMin, pointMax + 1))
      .orient('top');

    let lineAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(line)
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickValues(d3.range(lineMin, lineMax + 1))
      .orient('left');

    let zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(point)
      .y(line)
      .scaleExtent([0.1, 1])
      .on('zoom', () => {
        let width = Math.min(viewWidth - margin.left - margin.right, chartWidth);
        let height = Math.min(viewHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom, chartHeight);
        let t = zoom.translate();
        let tx = Math.min(t[0], 0);
        tx = Math.max(tx, width - chartWidth);
        let ty = Math.min(t[1], 0);
        ty = Math.max(ty, height - chartHeight);
        zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
        let scale = zoom.scale();

        svg.select('.x.axis').call(pointAxis).selectAll('text')
          .attr('x', -3)
          .attr('y', 5)
          .attr('transform', 'rotate(90)')
          .style('text-anchor', 'end');
        svg.select('.y.axis').call(lineAxis);

        grid.attr('transform', `translate(${[tx, ty]})scale(${scale})`);
      });

    let svg = d3.select('.chart').append('svg')
      .attr('id', 'svg')
      .attr('width', viewWidth)
      .attr('height', viewHeight)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
      .call(zoom);

    let grid = svg.append('g')
        .attr('id', 'grid');

    // Add the grid background
    grid.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'grid')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', chartWidth)
      .attr('height', chartHeight);

    // Create the cells
    let cell = grid.selectAll('.cell')
      .data(markers).enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('id', (marker) => `cell${marker.line}-${marker.point}`)
      .attr('class', 'cell')
      .attr('transform', (marker) => `translate(${point(marker.point) - cellSize / 2}, ${line(marker.line) - cellSize / 2})`);

    cell.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'border')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', cellSize)
      .attr('height', cellSize);

    cell.append('rect')
      .attr('class', (marker) => `fill valid`)
      .attr('x', borderSize)
      .attr('y', borderSize)
      .attr('width', cellSize - 2 * borderSize)
      .attr('height', cellSize - 2 * borderSize);

    cell.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'selection')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', cellSize)
      .attr('height', cellSize);

    // Add the axes
    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .call(pointAxis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('x', -3)
      .attr('y', 5)
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(90)')
      .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(lineAxis);
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are _not_ clipping anything. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to actually use `clipPath`, you could just add a simple bg for x axis like this before you add the axes.

```
  // Add bg for x axis
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('height', 30)
    .attr('y', -25)
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('width', chartWidth);
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/tVZb7YEaDTMZaFX4Nod3?p=preview

Comment: I didn't add any background for the axes because all the examples I found using d3.js don't have to do it to 'clip' properly.
For example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928
or http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

Comment: Not really comparable. Those examples draw a grid with d3 axes. You are drawing a grid by just appending rects.